# American and Japanese Nintendo Zone for HomePass

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

I've recently set up my own **HomePass Relay** for my Nintendo 3DS, but the only Nintendo Zone MAC addresses I've found online seem to be from German hotspots.
I have now completed the whole Germany, so it will be nice to complete other countries.

Does anybody know any American or Japanese Nintendo Zone MAC address for HomePass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to a [GoogleDocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvvH5W4E2lIwdEFCUkxrM085ZGp0UkZlenp6SkJablE#gid=0%20Original%20reference%20thread:%20%20) list of MACS from the [gbaTemp forum](https://gbatemp.net/threads/how-to-have-a-homemade-streetpass-relay.352645/). If you download it, it should help.

Sorry I can't help more than that, but I haven't figured out how to homepass myself yet. All I can do is give links. ;-_-;

Comment: I have this list too, but I don't know why I can use only the addresses in the first tab. It seems that Windows doesn't allow me to use a MAC address that starts with 00.